# Where is the argument of stdlib.h's system() function in x86_64 assembly labguage?

Tags: assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

I'm new to systems security, and I'm trying to implement a simple return-to-libc exploit. With GCC's `-fno-stack-protector` set, now I know how to smash the return address by utilizing a buffer overflow bug. Now I'd like to direct the control flow of the target program to C's `system()` function by overwriting a correct return address of a function with the address of `system()` (I compile the program with `-static` option set so that all C's standard functions are in the executable code).  For example, the target program is like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[8];
    gets(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I can overwrite `main()`'s return address with the address of `system()` that I find by gdb's disassemble function. I'd like to provide "/bin/sh" as the argument of `system()`, but I don't know where the argument of `system()` function is on the address space. Could anyone help me figure out where I can find the argument?

Answer (score 5):

The calling convention used on x86-64 passes arguments in registers. The first argument is passed in RDI. This is a major difference from x86, where arguments are typically passed on the stack.

To pass a crafted argument to a function, you will need to make it be present in RDI, either by:

1. Making `main()` put that value there. (Probably impossible in this situation.)
2. Use a ROP gadget. Find the instruction sequence `pop %rdi; retq` in memory, then return to the address of that sequence with the addresses of `"/bin/sh"` and `system()` on the stack, in that order.

   If you can't find that exact sequence, you may be able to use a different pop-and-return sequence that includes RDI, and push extra junk values to accomodate it. For instance, if you find a `pop %rdi; pop %rbp; retq`, you'd push an extra value after the crafted RDI.